# Why Laravel keeps calling schedule() with every Artisan Command?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron

I have one table called `dc_user_meta` and I've created one artisan command and scheduled it in `kernel.php`. Just after cloning the repository, when I try to run `PHP artisan migrate`, I get this error.

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                              
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'database.dc_user_meta' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `dc_user_met  
  a` where `meta_key` = usage_in_days)
```

Not only `php artisan migrate` but I am unable to run any artisan command at all! I don't know why PHP keeps calling `schedule` method every time I try to execute any artisan command.

Here in this case, What I can do to solve this error is put the cover over my logic in `schedule` method just like this.

```
if(Schema::hasTable('dc_user_meta')){
    // Code here
}
```

But I don't think it's good in Long run. What's the right way to solve this error?

**UPDATE:**
I just tried covering call to command in `kernel.php` just like this but still no success!

```
if(Schema::hasTable('dc_user_meta')){
    $schedule->command('usage:update')->daily();
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I got the solution. But I don't think it's the answer to the question. It solves my problem but I don't think it's standard Solution. I just covered by Command login just like this.

```
if(Schema::hasTable('dc_user_meta')){
    // Command Logic
}
```

Any specific answer to why Laravel calls **schedule()** with every `artisan` command and how to solve the error in a standard way if something like this happens!

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce it (L5.4) I made a command calling a non existing table, but only get an error when calling it.

Comment: @cbaconnier create table in database and then try to run "php artisan migrate:refresh"

Comment: which version of Laravel are you using ?

Comment: I am using laravel5.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically the schedule method ist called via the constructor of **Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel** ( This is the parent class of app\Console\Kernel.php)

So every time the console Kernel is instantiated, the schedule() method gets executed.

Let's see what gets executed in which scenario ( $schedule->call() can be replaced with $schedule->command() or $schedule->exec()):

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    // everything that is inside the schedule function is executed everytime the console kernel is booted.

    // gets exectuted every time
    \App\User::where('foo', 1)->get();


    $schedule->call(function() {
        // gets executed for every call to php artisan schedule:run
        \App\User::where('foo', 1)->get();
    });

    $schedule->call(function() {
        // gets executed for every call to php artisan schedule:run
        // IF the closure in the when() function is true;

        \App\User::where('foo', 1)->get();
    })->when(function() {
         // if true is returned the scheduled command or closure is executed otherwise it is skipped
         \Schema::hasColumn('user', 'foo');
    });

}
```

### But why HAS the schedule command to be exectuted with every command?

Well, obviously **php artisan schedule:run** is a console command itself. So it definitely needs information about scheduled commands.

Also other commands could need information about scheduled commands... For example if you want to write an artisan command **list:scheduledTasks**. This command would require that all scheduled commands have been added to the console schedule list.

Maybe there are several other (internal) arguments why the schedule function has to run everytime. ( I did not dig too deep in the source code... )
Nevertheless... information about scheduled commands could be useful to a variety of use cases.

Comment: So, what's the best way to write the command logic that works with the database as well as we can run `php artisan migrate` and `php artisan migrate:refresh`.

Comment: I would use the last example with the when() method. So the command is only executed if the requirements ( in your case the presence of a specific table) is fulfilled. php artisan migrate and php artisan migrate:refresh are not affected at all, if you encapsulate your code in $schedule->command() or $schedule->call()

Comment: So, It's the standard way to get rid of this error. To check if table exists before executing exact command logic. Right?

Comment: It is the only possible way to avoid errors.... BUT if you don't use the when() function like in the example. Then the command is not scheduled at all ( And so no other commands or processes have information about scheduled commands).  Your example will work, if you don't need that at all.

Comment: Cool then! that's what I wanted to know!

Answer (score 1):

Your error is with table `dc_user_meta` while your logic is of table `user_meta` you need to do `Schema::hasTable('dc_user_meta')`

Answer (score 0):

I'm convinced that table dc_user_meta doesn't exist in database.

Comment: It should work if your code doesn't have any errors. Somewhere in your code there's a bug that's causing migration to fail. Do: `php artisan migrate -vvv` to see the full stack and post here

Comment: trying. Will let you know what happens!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, yor have table "user_meta" not "dc_user_meta" but you have written the code to use table "dc_user_meta" hence there is an error saying "dc_user_meta" table not found.

Comment: It's `dc_user_meta`. `dc_` is prefix. Just to show you the name of the table, I wrote `user_meta`. Actual table name is `dc_user_meta` and i wrote code for `dc_user_meta`.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone still cares about this...

```php
<?php
# This is your app/Console/Kernel.php
use ...;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel {

    # Other stuff...

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {
        if( in_array('schedule:run', $_SERVER['argv']) ){
            # Your scheduler commands here...
        }
    }

}
```